# How to generate a table of contents when converting from LaTeX to EPUB using Pandoc?

Tags: latex, ebook, table-of-contents, epub, pandoc

I'm converting a LaTeX document into an EPUB ebook:

```
pandoc input.tex -o output.epub
```

Everything works fine, however the ebook has a broken TOC: It contains only one item - the book's title. How can I make the TOC to contain all parts or all chapters of my book?

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult for Pandoc to process all types of LaTeX code as input.

However, you should add `--toc --toc-depth=N` (where `N` is a digit indicating the depth of the ToC you want to generate.

I've had good success converting some critical LaTeX source files to EPUB by...

- ...first converting to Markdown,
- ...then hand-massaging the b0rken parts into proper Markdown,
- ...last converting from Markdown to EPUB.